# How can sizeof determine size of an array, if it's length is determined on runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime, sizeof

As much as I know, sizeof can only know size of something, if the size is determined at runtime.

```
int a1;
cin>>a1;
int x2[a1];
cout<<sizeof(x2)/4<<"\n";
```

If I give input 10, sizeof says the size of the array is:`40/4=10` 
How can sizeof know this?

Comment: `int x2[a1];` is a non-Standard extension to C++, and in order to make it work, the implementers had to break the hell out of the `sizeof` operator's compile-time only nature. Basically `sizeof` is compile-time when the size can be determined at compile time and isn't compile time when given an object that can only be sized at runtime.

Comment: The very short answer is to change to use `std::vector` instead of what you're doing now. It was made for this kind of thing.

Comment: What language are you using `C` or `C++`?  They are different languages.

Comment: `int x2[a1];` -- This is a non-starter.  This is not valid C++ code, thus the solution is to "not do this" and instead use `std::vector`.  Also this is why I hope at some point, `g++` and `clang` compilers change their defaults to **not** have extensions enabled, so that new programmers don't continually come across this issue.  There are literally thousands of questions from new programmers using the same non-standard syntax, all because they use `g++` or `clang` in their default compile settings.

Comment: @user4581301 So in C, sizeof can only know the size on compile-time and in c++ it can know the size even if it is determined on runtime?

Comment: @darthvader123 -- Pretend the code you wrote could never have been written for C++.  That's the bottom line.  It doesn't exist because it is not C++.  If you had used [Visual Studio](https://godbolt.org/z/M59PMjYWM) instead of `g++`, you would not have even gotten past the compile stage, since that compiler rightfully rejects that syntax.

Comment: In C Variable Length Arrays are legal (as of C99, but made optional in C11) and `sizeof` may or may not have been computed at compile-time. In Standard C++ `sizeof` is always computed at compile-time, but compiler implementers are allowed to add functionality to a compiler and some have (for the most part) duplicated C's behaviour.

Comment: @user4581301: But please note that the C++ proposal for "array of runtime bound" makes `sizeof` an error, it does not work like C `sizeof` on VLAs.

Comment: @BenVoigt A simple fix for an ugly problem. Easily managed, too. If you sized the array, you should have a variable hanging around somewhere holding that size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's worse. VLAs are enabled in gcc/clang with `-std=c++20`. Even with `-pedantic` they are only a warning. Other extensions require to use `std=gnu++20`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- So I guess the VLA's we see in C++ code from newbies will not end in the near future.  You can add to the mounting questions this one: "Why does this code not compile in Visual Studio?  It works in CodeBlocks", and when you see the code, yep, full of VLA's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in C, sizeof can only know the size on compile-time and in c++ it
> can know the size even if it is determined on runtime?

No, it is wrong.

**C** && **C++** (C++ VLA is a GCC extension) Compiler will emit the constant value if `sizeof` is used on something whose size can be determined compiler time, or will emit some code to calculate it at runtime if it is not possible to evaluate it compile time.

Comment: `No, it is wrong.` if would say it's not wrong, but rather `you are right if we don't use any C++ extensions`

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Yes, C++ has _dialects_ like many other languages, like _C_, which more or less promotes adding extensions. I think (my opinion), that C++ is _more_ constrained - and very few extensions works while still maintaining 100% compatibility with the language standard the extensions are supposed to extend. C++ is  _complicated_. I've had plenty of standard code compile fine when turning off extensions - which makes that clear/(a big issue). +1